# Compass and sass-globbing 'file to import not found or unreadable' error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass-sass, sass-globbing

I'm new to sass-globbing and gems as a whole so I'm sorry if this question mixes many topics.

The problem is that I'm trying to watch my project with compass and I'm getting the error:

> File to import not found or unreadable:  `<pathtofile>`

This is caused by an import that uses `@import 'folder/*';` but my understanding is that the sass-globbing gem should allow this usage.

I've got `require 'sass-globbing'` inside compass.rb and I've also got `gem 'sass-globbing'` inside the project gemfile, and I've even tried specifying the version to `1.1.0` following a suggested fix elsewhere but to no avail.

I'm completely stuck on this and can't work on this project until it's resolved!